# Dropping of function

Tags: linux-kernel, device-driver

While searching for __exit use in kernel code . I came across https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-hacking/routines-init.html
where it is written as
"__exit is used to declare a function which is only required on exit: the function will be dropped if this file is not compiled as a module."

I don't know what does dropping of function mean. It would be great help if anyone delineate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the memory used for the `__exit` executable code is reclaimed and the `__exit` will not be available in memory (since it will never be called for things which are not modules.)

Comment: Does it mean that it clears the memory occupied by function which are called during exit of driver or it mean that it clears the memory of function occupied during execution of exit.

Comment: All functions and init data which are marked with `__init`, `__initdata` or `__exit` are cleared.  These markings put them into special linker sections which the kernel code looks for and releases when it is done with them.  It does not exhaustively search through all symbols called by these exit or init entry points and release other calls.